# User profile merge

Tags: support, status-completed

A user has contacted me regarding a merge of accounts.

He had this account on the old site:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/575/ionline247?tab=stats

with rep of 425, but can't log into it (listed as Unregistered User).

He cab only this one:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/4072/ionline247?tab=accounts

with the account linked to StackOverflow.

He's asking for the profiles to merge. He'd ask himself but needs a rep of at least 5 to post, the account he *can* get into is a fresh account with a rep of 1.

Comment: Also, you don't need to flag since we get automatically notified for new meta posts.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, didn't know that. Cheers Kit :)

Answer (score 1):

I've merged the two accounts for him:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/4072/ionline247

Comment: Thanks guys for getting me sorted.  It's been a bummer w/o my stackexchange fix.